# if && not true && not true && not true returning true

Tags: php, if-statement

I'm checking if user `$_SESSION` variables are populated and if the login is correct. This is my code:

```
if(!empty($_SESSION['user'])&&!empty($_SESSION['pwd'])&&!verifyLogin($_SESSION['user'],$_SESSION['pwd'])){
```

`$_SESSION['user']` is username, `$_SESSION['pwd']` is password, `verifyLogin()` is my function for validating user's login.

Why does my if statement returns true even if `$_SESSION['user/pwd']` are empty? Shouldn't I get back false?

Even if I do this:

```
if(!empty($_SESSION['user'])&&!empty($_SESSION['pwd'])&&verifyLogin($_SESSION['user'],$_SESSION['pwd'])==false){
```

I still get the same result.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you `var_export($_SESSION)` and paste the results here as a code block? (that's `var_export` and not `var_dump`)  With that information someone will be able to help you.

Comment: Also, with the nature of `$_SESSION` you may want to try `isset()` over `empty()`.

Comment: I just tested with normal variables and it works fine. Triple-check that those variables contain what you think, and that you don't have any typos in your code.

Comment: Alan Storm: if user is logged in then the variables are populated, but when is not they are empty.
@Utoxin: No typos, just incorrect usage of empty(), as Brad Christie pointed out :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your check to use [`isset`](http://www.php.net/isset) over `empty`. `empty` will return true of it's empty, but also if it's not set. Check out [this post about the difference](http://www.virendrachandak.com/techtalk/php-isset-vs-empty-vs-is_null/).

```
if (isset(_usr_) && !empty(_usr_) // exists and isn't empty
 && isset(_pwd_) && !empty(_pwd_)
 && verifyLogin(_usr_, _pwd_)){
}
```

From the manual of [`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php):

> Returns FALSE if var **exists and has a non-empty, non-zero value**. Otherwise returns TRUE.

i.e. not set will return `TRUE`.

Comment: but if it returns true, the expression evaluates to false.